# Android making an scrolled two independent listview in activity

Tags: java, android

I am working in Android Studio in a new app and I want to create a layout with two independent scrolled listview (each listview scrolling in independent way) in the same activity. I cannot obtain the target that I want. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I am **not sure about efficient way** but I worked in following way.
First, I have created two dynamic ListView and put in into one activity.

It will calculate the height dynamically rather than match_parent.

Here is the code:

```
 public void setListViewDynamicHeight(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = listView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = height + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build it in your layout xml like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hallo!" />

            <!--Other views inside NestedScrollView-->
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hallo!" />

            <!--Other views inside NestedScrollView-->
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```